# nservicebus 4.03, installing performance counters for 3.3.4 and 4.03

Tags: performance, nservicebus

We have got multiple application running on different version of nservicebus on the same servers.
Would I be able to install performance counters for both the version?
Would this cause any issues?
The newer version provides more counters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any difference between the performance counters for V3 and V4. In essence, they are the same counters. If you install them with V3, and then try to install them with V4, the V4 installer should check for them, see that they exist, and do nothing.

The only exception would be if a new version of NServiceBus adds additional performance counters, in which case you should obviously make sure that you have installed them for the most recent version. That is my advice in the general sense anyway - I don't think that's the case for V4 specifically.